# Is it possible to generate xsd inside WSDL with JAX-WS?

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I am using JAX-WS 2.2 inside my WebApplication to generate a WSDL.
It works correctly but I wish I could generate the xsd internal to the WSDL, instead of having the pointer to another url.
I saw here (https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-85) but it is referred to the wsgen.   Is it possible to reach this goal with an annotation?

Comment: You can insert generated schema in WSDL using `-inlineSchemas`

Comment: Thank you very much, but I was looking for an option in the code section because I would like to generate the WSDL   on the web app with the xsd inside the types section.   The -inlineSchemas works good and generates me what I want but I would like to see it when I deploy the web application on Tomcat.